# side bar wrong position

Tags: php, css, wordpress, templates, sidebar

Im trying to get a sidebar in php in the right position.
I have made a template in php and work with responsive css. But every time I
try to put the sidebar its appear in the last horizontal position of the first post I made

See the example below

http://profesorprofesor.net63.net/error.png

Is there a way to refresh or move the pink side bar correctly?

Please help me I have try all the day trying to fix the problem.

Here are the php code:

```
      <div class="post">
      <article>
      <header class="wp">
      <h2><a href=" <?php the_permalink(); ?>">   
      <?php the_title(); ?> </a></h2>            
      <div class="entry">
      <p>   <?php the_content(); ?> </p>
      <p class="postmetadata">
      <?php _e('Filed under&#58;'); ?> 
      <?php the_category(', ') ?> 
      <?php _e('by'); ?> 
     <?php  the_author(); ?>    <br/>
    <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?> 
    <?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' &#124; ', ''); ?>
    </p> 

    </div>
    </header>
    </article>
     </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>  
    <?php endif; ?>

<div class="alado" > gola</div>

<aside>
     <h3>Ignacio Nieto, </h3>
    <p> </aside>
```

Comment: Please post all the HTML- and CSS-code for the relevant page.

Comment: The code is too long it doesnt fit here. I send a link where i uploaded http://profesorprofesor.net63.net/compress.zip Is only the main html and the main css

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you wish to always keep the right hand navigation bar at the top right hand side of the page no matter how many posts there are. Correct? If so, why don't you absolutely position this div? This way it's position will be maintained. If this is not what you are trying to achieve, could you please make your question clearer.

Comment: Dear JezzpinYes your are correct. Sorry for my bad english is not my native languague. If I made abosute to the position it will not be responsive. So it will not move if I saw it in a mobile device. I try it before.

Comment: In this sense, what do you mean by responsive? Moves down the page depending on the number of posts?

Comment: if a saw it in another resolution -mobiles devices- the sidebar must go down after the comments and before the footer

Comment: Okay. That's fine. In that case you should generally have an alternative stylesheet that kicks in when the viewport is smaller. Using something along the lines of <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"> to include the css. This is one of the easiest and safest ways of creating adaptive layouts. You would then overwrite your underlying styles using: @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {   
    /* Mobile Styling here*/ 
}

Comment: I got it like that the responisive is working in several resolutions but the position of the side bar in "normal" resolution is always under the first post

Comment: What do you consider normal resolution? You should set default properties for the menu that apply to 1024 x 768 and then overwrite them with your media specific variations.

Comment: Thanks a lot I fixed using your specifications

Comment: I will amend my answer shortly to summarize this discussion. Once I have done so if you would be so good as to mark my answer as correct, that would be great!